# How to observe transfer characteristics of MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet

I have built a simple Mosfet circuit now I want to check the Vds vs Id characteristics.

[image]

But the problem is when the Vcc(Supply) and Vgs(Gate to Source) (according to the following characteristics) is fixed how can I increase Vds to observe the (Vds vs Id) characteristics?

[image]

Comment: Did you believe that you could measure it while it was in a circuit?

Comment: So how can i measure ???
I have build a circuit to measure it characteristics

Comment: Remove it from the circuit. Put it in a test jig.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace resistor and led with a potentiometer, and use the potentiometer to create a sweep in both Ids and Vds.

You'll need to measure both by means of a multimeter, and tune the potentiometer in order to get the desired voltage or current steps. You don't actually need to know the value of the resistor as long as you can measure Vds and Ids.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f33WN4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that doing this you might apply Vcc over the channel of your transistor, and that can or cannot be a good idea, depending on the voltage. For this sake you might consider putting another series resistor.